# jQuery pop up box overlay not closing

Tags: php, jquery, popup

I am using a pre-existing jQuery popup plugin for a WordPress site.  The popup works great but the only problem is the styling - it didn't include any sort of "overlay" in the design.  Since I want the background to "grey out", I set out to adding some classes and styles to the css to make this happen, but am running into a wall.

Here was the original HTML:

```
<div id="messagebox" class="visiblebox">
    <a href="" id="closebox" title="Close this box"></a>
    <div id="message">message content</div>
</div>
```

And I added a div above that to create this HTML:

```
<div id="popupOverlay" class="visiblebox"></div>
<div id="messagebox" class="visiblebox">
    <a href="" id="closebox" title="Close this box"></a>
    <div id="message">message content</div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS - I added the 2nd line to the removeMessageBox function below after editing my HTML per above:

```
function removeMessageBox() {
    jQuery(this).parent('#messagebox').removeClass('visiblebox').addClass('hiddenbox');
    jQuery(this).parent('#popupOverlay').removeClass('visiblebox').addClass('hiddenbox');
    return false;
}


function boardReady() {
    jQuery('#closebox').click(removeMessageBox);
    jQuery('#messagebox').css('visibility', 'visible');
}

jQuery(window).load(boardReady);
```

And here is some corresponding CSS:

```
div#popupOverlay.visiblebox {display: block;}
div#popupOverlay.hiddenbox {display: none;}
div#messagebox.visiblebox {display: block;}
div#messagebox.hiddenbox {display: none;}
```

Of course, it's not working.  I barely know any JS so I'm not sure exactly what to add to the right function to get the same effect of the close action when clicked on the close link.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `popupOverlay` is supposed to achieve, but could it be that it sits on top of your `closebox` link making it unclickable?

Comment: Could you link us to the actual plugin? Or at least supply us the css for both messagebox and popupoverlay?

Comment: @Tomm - No, the other styles have z-indexes that make them all sit on there in the correct order.  When you click the CLOSE button on the popup, it closes fine, but the OVERLAY behind it (which has an opaque color style applied to it) stays put, rendering the entire site impossible to use.

Comment: @Purmou, actually it's not a free plugin (it's one on WPMUdev), so not sure if I can share the files due to license restrictions?  But I'll paste the css below...

Comment: CSS: http://pastebin.com/FSNFfGF3  -- You can see the problems on the live site by visiting http://www.appthemes.com/showcase/ and then scrolling down to the bottom left image called "Running Horses Classified Ads" -- the reason I'm using this particular popup is because it has an easy referral function to it and I only want the popup to display to people visiting the site from this referrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see. Why don't you try this

```
function removeMessageBox() {
    jQuery('#messagebox').removeClass('visiblebox').addClass('hiddenbox');
    jQuery('#popupOverlay').removeClass('visiblebox').addClass('hiddenbox');
    return false;
}
```

There is no need for all the jQuery traversing (i.e. using the `.parents()` method) as both elements have unique IDs. The problem with your code is that `#popupOverlay` is not a parent of `closebox`.